# Connect AWS S3 via nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have created a java client to upload files to S3 buckets using the AWS SDK. It works perfectly fine.

Now I am trying to do the same thing with Nginx in the middle. As in all the request from my client will pass through NGINX.

I new to Nginx so somehow compiled this nginx.conf

```
events {}
http {

  server {
    listen 9091;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://bucket-name.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/;
    }
  }
}
```

This config gives the below exception:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: 7BB1301CCDE06B05; S3 Extended Request ID: qAVh3RMieyqgwOrzNeiMAVQyb9V59J0rThHYqnfzUibZxqDIzzMUPI8SdWLCa9tL15YyekI2ukQ=), S3 Extended Request ID: qAVh3RMieyqgwOrzNeiMAVQyb9V59J0rThHYqnfzUibZxqDIzzMUPI8SdWLCa9tL15YyekI2ukQ=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1799)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1383)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1359)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1139)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:796)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:764)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:738)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:698)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:680)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:544)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:524)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5052)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4998)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.initiateMultipartUpload(AmazonS3Client.java:3574)... 19 more
```

I tried to tweak the configs but couldn't succeed.

Comment: Have you considered using [presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObjectJavaSDK.html) to upload directly to S3 from the client? I'm trying to understand the need for Nginx in the middle

Comment: I have a requirement. I have written a retry logic that will retry if S3 is not available. For this, I have to write a  test case. To replicate this scenario I want to use Nginx. So that I can interrupt connection by killing Nginx container.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the **Host** header originally used by the client (Nginx rewrites this header by default), since AWS signature is also calculated from this field.

The Nginx config may look like (note the added `proxy_set_header` line):

```
events {}
http {

  server {
    listen 9091;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header       Host $http_host;
      proxy_pass http://bucket-name.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/;
    }
  }
}
```

This is based on the following answer from another StackOverflow problem:
[Nginx confg issue - couldn't connect to S3 compatible storage from NodeJS test program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53833505/nginx-confg-issue-couldnt-connect-to-s3-compatible-storage-from-nodejs-test-p)