# Spring Cloud Gateway to S3 SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: amazon-s3, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway, aws-s3-client

I am trying to use Spring Cloud Gateway to redirect to our S3 server. The problem is that when redirecting I get the error:

> SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

I have the following configuration on application.yml:

```
      - id: example-s3
        predicates:
        - Path=/example-s3/**
        uri: ${project.services.internal.example-s3.url}      
        filters:
        - RewritePath=/example-s3/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
        - PreserveHostHeader
```

I added the option -PreserveHostHeader because it was failing and I saw this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53833505/nginx-confg-issue-couldnt-connect-to-s3-compatible-storage-from-nodejs-test-p) that works with nginx. It works with nginx but not with Spring Cloud Gateway.

I don't know what else to do, I have compared the headers using nginx and using Spring Cloud Gateway and I don't see anything else that might be necessary.

If I add - RemoveRequestHeader=Authorization then it works on public objects, but it does not work when it is private. So I think the problem must be in that header. It is:

```
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=XXXXXXXX/20230324/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-user-agent, Signature=fake-signature-to-sctackoverflow
```

I have seen that for signing (SignedHeaders) it use the headers host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-user-agent and I verify that these headers are present. In nginx the host header is stripped by Nginx by default, so the solution I added in nginx works, but in Spring Cloud Gateway I am not able to make it work.

I don't know what else to try or do, how to reverse proxy it correctly with Spring Cloud Gateway?

Answer (score 0):

do not use RewritePath filters, this will change the 'Host' of S3.
It can work like this:

```
  - id: example-s3
    predicates:
    - Path=/**
    uri: ${project.services.internal.example-s3.url}      
    filters:
    - PreserveHostHeader
```

Comment: How can redirecto to the correct path if I don't use RewritePath? @yuanzhi

Comment: You can regenerate AWS sign in Spring Cloud Gateway                                    
Demo like this: https://github.com/yzh19961031/blogDemo/tree/master/s3-gateway